# How to modify single character after a specified character? (PHP)

Tags: php

I'd like to capitalise the character after each opening bracket, i.e. change strings like:
"Apple (juice)" to "Apple (Juice)"  and "Steve (hobs) Ra" to "Steve (Hobs) Ra"

How can I do this in PHP?

Thanks

Comment: 1. `strpos` for `(` 2. `strtoupper` for a character after it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to check for words inside parenthensis, then [`ucfirst`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) to change first letter to uppercase

```
$pattern = '/\((.*?)\)/';
$string = '"Apple (juice)" "Steve (hobs) Ra"';

$newstr = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($matches) {
    return '(' . ucfirst($matches[1]) . ')';
}, $string);

echo $newstr;
```

Another way is with a `while` loop and [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to check for opening parenthesis, then [`strtoupper()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) to change the letter to upper case

```
$string = '"Apple (juice)" "Steve (hobs) Ra"';

$pos = 0;
while ($pos = strpos($string, '(', $pos)) {
    $string[++$pos] = strtoupper($string[$pos]);
}

echo $string;
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP explode function then convert each the first character by using ucfirst function. See code below:

```
$str = '"Apple (juice)" "Steve (hobs) Ra"';
$array = explode("(", $str);
$new_str = '';
foreach($array as $x => $y){
    if($x != 0){
        $new_str .= "(";
    }        
    $new_str.=ucfirst($y);
}
echo $new_str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple trick you can try this. It might help you.

```
$str = "Apple (juice)";

for( $i = 0; $i <= strlen( $str ); $i++ ) {

    if( $str[$i] == '(')
          $str[$i+1] = strtoupper($str[$i+1]);
}

echo $str;
```